# How to auto adjust the views in Android Studio 3.0 according to the screen size of the device

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio-3.0

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3oBm2.png)I am unable to implement the auto-layout concept in Android Studio as i used to do in in Xcode.

Here are the screenshots, one is on Nexus One screen and another one is on Nexus 7's big screen. View aren't getting adjusted automatically according to the screen size.

Comment: Can you give your code example as well?

Comment: can i put my code in comment box ?

Comment: Its not letting me to add screenshots

Comment: you can use constraint layout to solve that

Comment: The android documentation talks extensively about multiple screen size support https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: @nguyencse yes i am using the same, design fits on Nexus one but it gets stuck at 0,0 on Nexus 7 screen (large screen).

Comment: @Zyzle link isn't solving my problem, do we have any thing like auto-layout in android ?

Comment: can you send your code? or I think the simplest way is design layout support multi screen with library "sdp"

link here: https://github.com/intuit/sdp

Comment: @nguyencse https://drive.google.com/open?id=1B6Po1_gyJqI3vcWztQOcnlE18dsQxDrF

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen your code but there are a few things you can try:

Use different drawables for different screen densities (`drawables-hdpi`, `drawables-xhdpi` and so on).

In your `.xml` file when defining your sizes use `dp` instead of `px`. `dp` or display pixels will fill the screen according to how many pixels there are rather than assuming there are the same amount of pixels on each screen.

Use Margins instead of absolute sizes. (e.g. `android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"`) would mean that that item lets say a button will be 2 display pixels from the left margin of the phone.

Comment: That's some good advice for using StackOverflow. Since it doesn't relate to the answer, specifically, maybe it should be posted as comments instead.